# Java code running twice

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have 2 Notes servers running from a load balancer.  The database uses directory services to authenticate to LDAP.

I have java code that checks LDAP to check if user's password is expired.  If the password is expired the code redirects to a password change screen.  This code runs in the before page load event.  Since all pages are NOT public access a Notes generated login occurs before anything takes place.

The password change screen first ties to authenticate the user in LDAP then changes the password.  But if I immediately change my password after the initial Note login then I get an authentication error.

If I change the password back to the same thing then I get no authentication error then everything works fine.

So I suspected that the java code was running twice.  The notes log should only running once.  But when our LDAP team turned on logging, they could see that the password attribute was being changed twice (when I changed to the same password).  So what was happening with the failure is that, the password was changed successfully but when the second time the code ran, it was using the "old" password and it was this error that was returned to the browser.

Now here is where it really gets strange.   If I do a Notes authentication,  then wait one full minute before password change, the code only runs once.

Or if I go to one of the servers, the code only runs once.

Code runs twice only if I go through the load balancer or if I try changing my password, immediately after logging in.

Any idea what on earth could be going on here?

Update:  The issue seems to be coming from our reverse proxy server.   The way our site is configured is Browser->Reverve Proxy->Load Balancer->(Notes Server 1, Notes Server 2).
If I go to the Load Balancer then the code only runs once.

While I might not be seeing logging in notes.nsf, I can see it running twice when I look direct at teh console.

Update:  Reverse Proxy is running on Apache.  Not sure the version.

Comment: Its difficult to tell just from the description. Will be helpful in analyzing if you can post more details like the code snippet that is responsible for checking with LDAP, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous password change page was refreshing the whole page when I pressed submit.  For some reason this was causing the page to be submitted twice.   I changed things to a partial refresh and now all works well.   Don'tknow why the refresh would not like the full refresh.   But it works now. :)